# removing json field from json element

Tags: postgresql

I have following data in details field (JSON):

```
{
  "display_data": {
    "_template": "activity/mr/updated.tpl",
    "user_name": "User",
    "id": 16808554
  },
  "display_data_title": {
    "_template": "activity/event_title/mr/updated.tpl",
    "is_task": false,
    "id": 16808554
  }
}
```

I want to remove `display_data->_template` and `display_data_title` field in SELECT query. I try with following query but it gives same result without removing those fields.

```
SELECT e.id
     e.details,
    e.details - '{ "display_data", "_template" }' AS new_details
FROM events e
     JOIN event_sub_types est ON (est.id = e.event_sub_type_id)
WHERE e.id= 1 AND
      e.property_id IN (7) AND
      e.event_type_id IN (2) 
ORDER BY e.id DESC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-` JSON operator only works for top-level elements. First cast `e.details` to JSONB (if not already so) and then use the [`#-`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSONB-OP-TABLE) JSONB operator.

```sql
SELECT e.id, e.details,
  e.details::jsonb #- '{display_data,_template}' #- '{display_data_title}' as new_details
FROM events e
-- ... the rest of your query
```